# Get values of table row and print them in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am retrieving values from database and print them in table. Now I want to get values to another div and place them in form.

I am using twitter bootstrap.

First I get values from database and print them in table

```
<div class="col-xs-10">
<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr class="bg-red">
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Quality</th>
        <th>Dimensions</th>
        <th>COlor</th>
        <th>Add</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    while($r=$q->fetch()){ ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?='Nb'. $r['Id']?> </td>
      <td> <?=$r['MatVrstaNaziv']?> </td>
      <td><?=$r['Quality']?></td>
      <td><?=$r['Width'] . '  X  '. $r['Height']?></td>
      <td><?=$r['COlor']?></td>
      <td> <button class="addValues" value="<?='Nb'. $r['Id']?> "> Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-2">
<div id="selection">

</div>

</div>
```

I have added button Add to add that row in another div. For that I am using script

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".addValues").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
        myCol = $this.closest("td"),
        myRow = myCol.closest("tr"),
        targetArea = $("#selection");
        targetArea.append(myRow.children().not(myCol).text() + "<br />");
    });
    });
</script>
```

This script does not work it does not print values in specified div. I only want to print id number in another div.

Could someone give me advice what is wrong?

Comment: Change `$("addValues")` to `$(".addValues")`.  Always debug your code - either step through or add `console.log("xxx")` - in this case right before `var $this = $(this)`.  It's probably not hitting that line.

Comment: `$("addValues")` you are missing a `.` selector `$(".addValues")`

Comment: I have added but nothing still happens.

Comment: "nothing" can be subjective - can you confirm that the event is being hit but adding the `console.log` as suggested?   What's the value of `targetArea.length` ?  Are any of the values null?  Does your php generate values in the row?  Is the an error in the console?   Do you really only want "id" - or is that just the first step to needing something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add `.` before addValues in selector `$(".addValues")` its work, see example bellow with static data.

If it still not working that mean you have problem in your PHP code, check if the query return valide result and check name of attributes like `'COlor'` for example.

```js
$(".addValues").click(function () {
 $('#selection').show();

    var $this = $(this),
    myCol = $this.closest("td"),
    myRow = myCol.closest("tr"),
    targetArea = $("#selection");
    var rowId = $("td.data-id", myRow).text();

 var qte_input = (' <input type="text" placeholder="Qte" size="5"/>');
    targetArea.prepend(rowId + qte_input +"<br />");
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-10">
<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr class="bg-red">
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Quality</th>
        <th>Dimensions</th>
        <th>COlor</th>
        <th>Add</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='data-id'> 1</td>
      <td> bb</td>
      <td> ccc</td>
      <td> dd  X  '. dd</td>
      <td> ee</td>
      <td> <button class="addValues" value="fff"> Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='data-id'>2</td>
      <td> YYY</td>
      <td> ccc</td>
      <td> dd  X  '. dd</td>
      <td> ee</td>
      <td> <button class="addValues" value="fff"> Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='data-id'>3</td>
      <td> XXX</td>
      <td> ccc</td>
      <td> dd  X  '. dd</td>
      <td> ee</td>
      <td> <button class="addValues" value="fff"> Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-2">
<div id="selection" style="display: none">
    </br>
    <button class="submitValues">Submit</button>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: It works, thank you I am using data tables for some reasons it does not work there. I was wondering how to get only Id value not the whole row?

Comment: Okay, where you want to use this id value?

Comment: My goal is to get all selected rows in different div. After each div I need to have input value where I will set quantity manually. Once that is completed there will be submit button to send those values

Comment: It still retrieves all row information. For example when I run your code i get    aaa bb ccc dd X '. dd ee Qte ...  I was wondering is it possible that I get only Id value from row and enter quantity after? I dont need name quality color information in another div just Id ??

Comment: Either `myRow.children().not(myCol).first().text()` which relies on the id being the first column, or, better, add a class to your `td` and use that.  I use 'data-' prefix to indicate the class is data and not style, eg:  `<td class='data-id'>aaa</td>` and `$("td.data-id", myRow).text()`

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m for your suggestion, check my updated answer.

Comment: @user3651819 check my updated answer based on freedomn suggestion.